# Why loading Force.com projects into Eclipse takes so long? Is there more dynamic way to load projects?

Tags: eclipse

Loading force.com projects into eclipse takes more than 2 hours and has become nightmare.

1. What could be cause? Is it system configurations?
2. It errors out while loading 3rd or 4th project. "Out of Stack memory" though I increased the size for workspace.
3. Is there any dynamic way to load the projects into eclipse in less than 5 min?

Comment: I had that problem years back I resorted to first creating a null project and then adding components in.

Comment: Although not an answer, I'd personally recommend Sublime Text with Mavensmate. Pretty easy to set up and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Addy, I tried similar way and it worked for me:

1. Add Force.com project and while adding metadata components Select "None" and hit "Finish". This will add only the project without any components.
2. Now, right click on the project --> Force.com --> select "Add/Remove Metadata Components"
3. Select the components you want to work (I prefer to select the developer components like "triggers, classes, pages, components etc") and hit OK followed by "Apply" which will add components into your workspace.

This way you can add whole Project into your workspace.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The slowness of the force.com IDE is due to overhead that comes along with using Metadata API, which the Force.com IDE is written on top of. In addition to this overhead, the Metadata API also requires polling to get results back, which adds a small delay.

Checking out less metadata in Eclipse might help you to get speed improvements.

You can check this [blog](http://www.tgerm.com/2010/03/fast-save-refresh-force-ide-eclipse.html) to setup selected components.